# Where to get "projects" to do / implement?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm doing a CS degree and right now I'm kind of bored (that's not the word, but I don't really know how to say it). I mean, I have lessons and all but right now I'm taking just a few courses so I have plenty of free time, so I would like to invest part of that time in programming something.

What I'm looking for are kind of specifications for projects, not just something that could be written in a couple of days but in a month or two, to keep me busy while learning new things.

Do anyone know of some sites where I could get that? May be didactical or not.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the projects on [projecteuler.net](http://projecteuler.net/). There's plenty of problems there to get your teeth into that'll challenge your maths and CS skills.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are hundreds and thousands of FOSS projects out there.  I would start looking at different ones and seeing where you're interested in helping out.  Contact the members and see if they want help.  I would recommend starting on a smaller project due to the fact that bigger projects have their own political/technical/etc. problems facing them which may hinder your learning.  But, of course, it is your choice.

Some places to start:

- http://code.google.com/ (more specifically - http://code.google.com/hosting/projects.html)
- http://www.sourceforge.net/

There are plenty of others.  Good luck, and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Look at some open source repositories - Sourceforge comes to mind. Find something that looks interesting and see what needs doing.